# Не работает сокет между клиентом и сервером Пайтон

Tags: python, сокет

Нужно сделать обмен данными между клиентом и сервером, все это реализовал через библиотеку socket, на моей машине при значении host='localhost' все работает и сервер получает сообщение от клиента. Но когда я выгрузил серверную часть на хостинг Амвера и обозначил host='*хост который мне дал Амвера*' сервер просто перестал получать сообщения от клиента. Клиент успешно коннектится к адресу сервера, отправляет сообщение, но сервер его не получает. В чем моя ошибка? порт 80 открыт

Клиент:

```
def sck(idu,name):
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect((host, 80))
    sock.send(bytes(idu+'<>'+'Скрипт '+name+' был завершен.','utf-8'))
    sock.close()
```

Сервер:

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('',80))
sock.listen(3)
def sockt():
    conn,addr = sock.accept()
    qw=conn.recv(1024).decode().split('<>')
    senderr(qw[0],qw[1])
```

sck() и sockt() бесконечно зациклены

Comment: А протокол указать на клиенте?

Comment: Если вы про socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, то добавил, до сих пор не работает